# Buddypress on Multisite - Member List

Tags: multisite, buddypress

I am using Buddypress on a multisite. The list of members on one site, includes members from the other site.

Is this correct, and if so, can it be changed?

I can try and use filters to restrict from 1 blog, but I am sure I will miss something somewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

BP on multisite can be quite complicated. 
If you network-activated BP, then afaik the users will be available on all 'blogs'. 
There are several ways to config a BP > multisite install. 
There are a couple of plugins that may help, for example: 
https://buddydev.com/plugins/buddypress-multi-network/

More info from the BP codex: 
https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/installation-in-wordpress-multisite/

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look.  A bit concerned that it doesn't seem to be updated very much - maybe it just works.